# Google Maps Api HTML5 Geolocation vs. Android Location API

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm working on a project which uses webview as frontend and xamarin mono (c#) as backend. When I try the html5 geolocation examples on google's maps api developer documentation, this one for example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

The location found with html5 in this example shows the city center, not my real coordinates. Yet google maps android, ios native application (and yandex application too) shows my exact coordinates with wifi on GPS off. Do I have to use android APIs to get real coordinates, or is there a way to get exact coordinates using solely javascript? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the exact geolocation using sole Javascript isn't possible with your gps in handheld devices. You need to use your Android Maps API or Google play services to get it done. On the other hand, you can get the geocode from an address in xml or json to your handheld using a simple HTTP request to maps.googleapis.com like this : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<address_string_goes_here>`